# Can we perform Validation of SCD type 2 in fact tables

Tags: testing, etl

Validation of (SCD) slowly changing dimension type 2 in fact tables

Answer (score 0):

To clarify the part let me define the terms for you in simple language:

***Dimension Table*** : The table with data that is relevant to the data warehouse

***Slowly Changing Dimension*** : The Dimensions in the tables change slowly with respect to time, i.e they maintain *historical* data.

***Fact Table*** : The Fact table contains primary key column for each dimension (in a connected Schema) with (not always) a serial number. Fact tables can consist of other values that cannot be associated with any dimensions.

So now to answer your question : The SCD 2 will be actually working over the records in the dimension table and not on the fact table. Fact table will only contain the dimension table's Primary key as a Foreign Key and some other values that will not be directly relevant to the DDL of the dimension table.

***TLDR*** ; No, The Fact table consist of Primary keys as Foriegn keys and hence cannot help in validation of data in SCD 2 such as Data duplicacy, data redundancy.